# Downloading files using httprequest

Tags: c#, download, httprequest

Is it possible to download files from a website using httprequest? I am only used to using it to get source code of a page. If there is no way to do it using httprequest, is there a way to download files using C# without having to use the webbrowser?

Edit: The answer must allow me to chose the location on the hard drive where the file will be downloaded to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely use `HttpRequest` by getting the `WebResponse` and using its response stream. Alternatively, use `WebClient`, with its [`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144193.aspx) and [`DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144187.aspx) methods to make life easier.

Ultimately there's not much difference between a request which gets a binary file as a response and a request which gets some HTML as a response. In some ways a binary response is *easier* to deal with, as you don't need to worry about character encodings.

Comment: @DazSlayer .. Why don't you try using these classes and try out a bit? :-)

Comment: @DazSlayer: Either use `WebClient.DownloadFile` or just open a `FileStream`, and repeatedly read from the response stream and write it to the file stream. If you're using .NET 4, there's even `Stream.CopyTo` to make this easier.

Comment: Will mark this as the answer if you can tell me how to change the location of where the file downloads to.

Comment: @DazSlayer: Just specify the full pathname either when constructing the FileStream or the WebClient.DownloadFile. You can use `Path.Combine` to obtain a full path from a foldername and a filename.

Comment: I am in a position where I need the `WebRequest` to do this because it can use a `CookieContainer`, and maintain a signed in session, ideal for crawling. This is not an answer for me, but I am glad it happened to solve the problem for the creator of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

use a **[WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** that wraps all of your needs to download data over http.

to get the source code of a page:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient ();
 string src = client.DownloadString(uri);
```

Comment: How do I change the location it downloads the file to?

Comment: this basically returns a string, use downloadFile ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194(v=vs.80).aspx) to set a path to download to (as @jonSkeet said ;)

Comment: The examples on the site only show how to download files to the startup path of the application, how can I have the user chose where to download the file to?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(downloadURL, fileName);
}
```

Comment: The 2nd parameter is the file name, not savePath

Comment: But =) I thought it would be easier to understand. Since i think it is a path and a filename...