# Convert CURL to C#

Tags: c#, http, post, curl

I have spent ages trying various different ways to convert this curl to c#. Could someone please help.
I am trying to do a http post and keep getting error 500.
here is what I want to convert:

```
curl --user username:password -X POST -d "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=http://www.google.com" http://crossbrowsertesting.com/api/v3/livetests/
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

var response = request.GetResponse();
string text;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    values.Add(text);
}
```

Tried this method too but it didn't work:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
        data.Add("browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome20|1024x768");
        data.Add("url=URL");
        data.Add("format=json");
        data.Add("callback=doit");
        var request = WebRequest.Create("CrossBrowserTestingURL");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write("data=" + data);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        string text;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            values.Add(text);
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to write the data into request stream..

Comment: could you please post a sample of how to do so. This is new to me. Thanks

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [.net - Making a cURL call in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp) or [c# - WebRequest Equivalent to CURL command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255725/webrequest-equivalent-to-curl-command#)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I modified the first one to write data to the request stream as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx, does this work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=http://www.google.com";

    streamWriter.Write(data);
}

var response = request.GetResponse();
string text;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    values.Add(text);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. Still getting error 500 from the server. The curl works but the c# method doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: I've changed the answer to use JSON as per the API docs, can you try again?

Comment: still returning error 500 internal server error unfortunately :(

Comment: I created an account to debug, the request data does have to be in form format and the **UserAgent** needs to be set. I used the cURL user agent for sake of testing. I guess the API is still in beta after all!

Comment: You will need to add a NameValueCollection right after your request.ContentType line. Like the following:  <br />    NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection()  <br />    collection.Add("username",value);  <br />    collection.Add("password", value);  <br />    request.Headers.Add(collection);

Answer (score 13):

Just implemented an experimental [ASP.NET Core app](https://github.com/olsh/curl-to-csharp) that turns curl commands into C# code using Roslyn

Give it a try, please:
https://curl.olsh.me/

Comment: This website sends your curl commands to its server to do the conversion. You may want to remove sensitive data from your command (such as cookies and OAuth tokens) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your command into [curlconverter.com/csharp/](https://curlconverter.com/csharp/) and it will convert it into this code using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0):

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://crossbrowsertesting.com/api/v3/livetests/");

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));

request.Content = new StringContent("browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=http://www.google.com");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```