# Convert Curl Script to C#

Tags: c#, curl

I have a curl script that downloads a file. How do I convert this to C#?

```
Dim strCurl1 
Dim strCurl2 
Dim strCurl3 
Dim strCurl4 

strCurl1 = "c:\temp\Curl\curl -d "
strCurl2 = "username=myUser&password=passwrd&asof=" & fileName & "&format=csv"
strCurl3 = "https://website/PresentValueServlet > " & "c:\temp\Curl\Results_" & fileName & ".csv"
strCurl4 = strCurl1 & Chr(34) & strCurl2 & Chr(34) & " " & strCurl3 & " --insecure  --proxy proxy.myserver.com:8080 --proxy-user admin:passAdmin"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "cmd /K " & strCurl4
```

My C# to date...

```
string username = "myUser";
string password = "passwrd";
string fileDestination = @"c:\temp\Curl\Results_" + fileName + ".csv";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
   client.DownloadFile(string.Format("https://website/PresentValueServlet"), fileDestination);
}
```

**Updated C# code with Proxy...**

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("myurl:8080", true);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "pswrd");
client.Proxy = proxy;
```

**Error**: *The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.*

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following options:

HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse
WebClient
HttpClient (available from .NET 4.5 on)

I'd highly recommend using the HttpClient class, as it's engineered to be much better (from a usability standpoint) than the former two.

In your case, you would do this:

```
using System.Net.Http;

var client = new HttpClient();

// Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new [] {
new KeyValuePair<string,>("text", "This is a block of text"),
});

// Get the response.
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
"http://api.repustate.com/v2/demokey/score.json",
requestContent);

// Get the response content.
HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

// Get the stream of the content.
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
// Write the output.
Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
}
```

this answer is from [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/580273/convertionplusofpluscurlplustoplusplusc).

Another refference i found [this](https://parse.com/questions/curl-and-c) solution in the net.

You can also try and look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306570/convert-curl-to-c-sharp) answer.

Comment: It works on a server that does not need a proxy. The curl script that works  uses... strCurl4 = strCurl1 & Chr(34) & strCurl2 & Chr(34) & " " & strCurl3 & " --insecure  --proxy muurl:8080 --proxy-user admin:pswrd"                           My C# code is updated in original post.                                                                                 Only difference looks to be use of _insecure_ in the curl script.