# C# command curl equivalent insecure

Tags: c#, api, curl

This is my curl command:

```
curl --insecure https://api.github.com/user?access_token=xxx
```

Is there a way to convert this into a C# code?
I've tried various solutions, but all failed.
I think the problem is the --insecure parameter.

This is my code:

```
String goodUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        String badUrl = "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=36905f6fffa42341c2e6fd12655295f2b4d25";
        var json1 = new WebClient().DownloadString(goodUrl);
        var json2 = new WebClient().DownloadString(badUrl);
```

GoodUrl is working fine, badUrl not.
The error is "protocol violation".

Comment: Do you just want the html or are you looking to download a file?

Comment: The output is just in json format.
I have to put the result into a simple var.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to this question, it shows a couple of ways to do something like this in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
```

Comment: Returns error "protocol violation", because I think SSL is not supported.

Comment: I did in the main post.