# Calling CURL using C#

Tags: c#, curl

I have to monitor an url that keeps streaming status of the system.
If i issue following command from Windows CMD `curl.exe http://localhost:8081/statusstream`,  I keep getting output from stream:

```
[02:10:51.021] Starting to execute testcase
[02:10:51.021] Test01: Preparing 
[02:11:03.089] Test01: Executing 1/10
[02:11:11.109] Test01: Executing 2/10
[02:11:19.126] Test01: Executing 3/10
[02:11:27.145] Test01: Executing 4/10
[02:11:35.163] Test01: Executing 5/10
[02:11:43.181] Test01: Executing 6/10
[02:11:51.198] Test01: Executing 7/10
[02:11:59.220] Test01: Executing 8/10
[02:12:07.237] Test01: Executing 9/10
[02:12:15.255] Test01: Executing 10/10
[02:12:33.274] Test01: Transferring data for analysis
[02:12:41.562] WARNING: TestSequencer: No data found
[02:12:41.563] Test01: Analyze results
[02:12:42.064] Test01: Finished executing
[02:12:42.064] Finished executing testcase
```

However when I run the same command using C#, I don't get any standard output, all I get is standard error. Following is my C# code

```
ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
_processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
_processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
_processStartInfo.FileName = "curl.exe"
_processStartInfo.Arguments = "http://localhost:8081/statusstream";

_process = new Process();
_process.StartInfo = _processStartInfo;
_process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
_process.ErrorDataReceived += _process_ErrorDataReceived;
_process.OutputDataReceived += _process_OutputDataReceived;
_process.Exited += _process_Exited;

_process.Start();

_process.BeginOutputReadLine();
_process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

The following method is always being hit, but not the the one which is waiting for StandardOutput

```
private void _process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        this.ConsoleLog = string.Format("[StdErr] {0}",e.Data);           
}
```

Output that i get from running CURL command from C# is:

```
    [StdErr]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
    [StdErr]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    [StdErr]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0     33      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    33
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0     18      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--    18
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0     12      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--    12
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      9      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     9
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      7      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     7
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      6      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      5      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      4      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      4      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      3      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      3      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100    40    0    40    0     0      3      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
    [StdErr] 100   112    0   112    0     0     16      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--    16
    [StdErr] 100   250    0   250    0     0     32      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--    47
    [StdErr] 100   250    0   250    0     0     29      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--    47
    [StdErr] 100   250    0   250    0     0     26      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--    47
```

If I see the received column, its value increases from 40 to 250, that means probably something is being return from the stream.

Issuing other HTTP GET commands from CURL using C# gives proper standardoutput. But other get commands return content immediately and are not streaming continuously.

Can someone please point what I'm doing wrong.

---

Ok, so I'm not supposed to call cURL.exe from C# code. But is there a way where I can monitor a URL to get continuous stream of data whenever there are updates? I don't want to call HttpClient GetStringAsync in a while loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a cURL call in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ok, so I'm not supposed to call cURL.exe from C# code. But is there a way where I can monitor a URL to get continuous stream of data whenever there are updates? I don't want to call HttpClient GetStringAsync in a while loop.

Comment: Use a timer to make the call every X seconds.