# Converting php to c#, curl to .net

Tags: c#, php, .net, curl

im trying to convert a PHP file to C#. the problem is that I don't know the equivalent .net commands to curl.

```
ob_start(); 
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch);
```

i have tried to find all this information but wheat i have found is only fractured bits of code that are incompatible.

Comment: SO isn't a "convert my code" service. Do please head over to [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and what kind of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: Possibly already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you're trying to implement some functionality in C#, then learning and writing some C# code would be a good place to start.  What specific functionality are you trying to implement?  What is stopping you from doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify anything, not even if it is a GET or POST, but this is an example from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) using restsharp

```
var client = new RestClient("https://google.com");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "49bab31b-6be2-5862-e3ca-351cb8b35d86");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```