# Use Hadoop FS in Windows IoT UWP programmatically

Tags: c#, hadoop, win-universal-app, windows-iot-core-10

Which possibilities are there to use [Hadoop file systems](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html) from .NET core (Windows IoT UWP) *programmatically*.

According to NuGET there are a bunch of libraries available to use in C# applications, but when googling each of them, I can't find any which will run in UWP. Are there any?

Or is the best way forward to write the HTTP GET/POST/PUT request myself using the `HttpClient` class e.g.? I've read [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp) on that topic as well, but of course I'd prefer a library where more experienced folks have solved the (for me not trivial) URL constructions for me.