# How to make cURL call in C#

Tags: c#, .net, curl

How can I make the following cURL call via C# console app.

```
curl -k https://serverName/clearprofile.ashx -H "Host: example.com"
```

I have tried [CurlSharp](https://github.com/masroore/CurlSharp/). Unfortunately I could not build successfully this project because of missing ***libcurlshim64*** assembly.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp) I understood that the best approach is by using `HttpClient` class, but I don`t know how exactly to make the above mentioned cURL call from my console application.

Comment: What code? The command line you posted simply runs a GET with a specific header. Have you checked HttpClient's documentation, eg HttpClient.GetStringAsync?

Comment: My bad, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want something simple I would use the HttpClient class built into the .Net Framework like this:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScrapCSConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "example.com";
            Task<string> task = client.GetStringAsync("https://serverName/clearprofile.ashx");
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }
    }
}
```

For more complex stuff, you can also use the HttpWebRequest class like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ScrapCSConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.co.uk");

            request.Host = "example.com";

            HttpStatusCode code;
            string responseBody = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    code = response.StatusCode;
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException webEx)
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response)
                {
                    code = response.StatusCode;
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {code}");
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had certificate error, so I just added a certificate validation handler right before the try/catch block. However, works perfectly now !