# how to get curl result in c#

Tags: c#, .net, curl

i has a example code in php for getting result from curl
but when i try call the function on c# i never get the result like php did

this is a code in php

```
$url = "http://localhost/ws/init.php";
$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);

$header=array();
$header[]='Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);


$data = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

this is the result from php

```
{"error_code":"0","error_desc":"","data":{"token":"xyx"}}
```

i try using libcurl.net,HttpClient,WebRequest, and WebClient for getting the result like php code did
but till now i still out of luck
maybe someone can help me for solved this problem?

i appreciated with ur help guys

thanks you before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a cURL call in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/)

example:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/ws/init.php");
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
var yourobject = new RequestObject(){....};
var json = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourobject);    
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var myResponseData = client.Execute<MyResponseObject>(request);
```

response objects

```
public class DataObject
{
    public string token { get; set; }
}

public class MyResponseObject
{
    public string error_code { get; set; }
    public string error_desc { get; set; }
    public DataObject data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient for this operation. You can use something like that

```
public async Task<JsonObject> GetAsync(string uri)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Parse(content));
    }
```

Comment: thank you for reply..the problem is i need to post json data to url and get the result.. i try this code but seems stuck at HttpResponseMessage HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, json); ;
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseBody;