# Windows application not running with curl

Tags: c#, curl

I have developed one windows application which uses curl.exe to get response from another one website. when i run this application in another one machine it throws an error "The program can't start because msys-curl-4.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".

So, I have added the required dll's in the same path from where i am running my application.

But now am getting a different error as in the image,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuABx.png)

Comment: possible duplication of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp)

Comment: so likely some dependancy is missing - please just post the errors not links to other sites with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Well, curl.exe uses the dll you have mentioned. It should be distrubuted with the executable. For C/C++ implementations using the DLL makes more sense. For C#, there are different classes where you can gain the same functionality as curl such as 'WebClient'.

---

I have an example in C++, I hope this helps. It uses curld.dll. For the usage check get_website function.
https://github.com/karusb/GW2-TP/blob/master/GW2TPAPI/GW2TPAPI.cpp