# Passing data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded in HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, x-www-form-urlencoded

- Passing data from **POSTMAN** as **x-www-form-urlencoded**
- Key and values are as follows:

```
data : P1;P2
format : json
```

Corresponding curl code from POSTMAN

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://ap-url/id/' \
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'data=P1;P2' \
```

How to send the data as x-www-form-urlencoded on HttpClient?

Comment: Duplicate of [Making a cURL call in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use https://curl.olsh.me/ for curl commands to C# code

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api-url/id"))
    {
        var contentList = new List<string>();
        contentList.Add($"data={Uri.EscapeDataString("P1;P2")}");
        contentList.Add($"format={Uri.EscapeDataString("json")}");
        request.Content = new StringContent(string.Join("&", contentList));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Pattern is to set a dictionary and send this dictionary data in the post method

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("mobile-server");

                var data = new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",
                        _configuration.GetValue<string>("MobileTop:ClientId")),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret",
                        _configuration.GetValue<string>("MobileTop:ClientSecret")),
                };
                var response =
                    await client.PostAsync("api/v2/connect/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
```