# how can deserialize data from http posted json file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

```
        var httpPostedJsonFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

        if (httpPostedJsonFile .ContentLength == 0)
        {
            VerboseReporter.ReportError("No file uploaded", "upload");
            return RespondFailure();
        }
```

Here httpPostedJsonFile is json file which posted from client side

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: how can i read http posted json file

Comment: Consult [Downloading files using HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856895/).